# Web App - Can i use Voice recognition in Dart+Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, voice-recognition

Before I spend a lot of time (I guess) reading up on SpeechSynthesisUtterance, is this the way to go to add voice recognition to my Dart+Polymer web app?

In fact, all I need is dictation (to fill in a text box). Nothing particularly clever (on my part at least!).

Or [polymer] "is there an element for that?" ;-)

cheers

Steve

Answer (score 0):

If it works in JS you can make it work in Dart. No need of Polymer but it will work with Polymer.dart as well.